# MovieClips on stage disappear

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip, stage

I am creating a miner game (where there are pieces of gold and you have to catch them with hook).
I modified the Main class to take all children of MovieClip(root) that has name "Gold" and them put them in an Array(boulders[]) where later check collision (I design and put on stage several "Gold" MovieClips for every level). When the player collects all gold (when the boulders array.length <= 0) then goToAndStop(nextLevel), where again it takes the gold MovieClips from the stage and if it's name is == "Gold" then put's it in the boulder[].
What happened:
On the first level (frame 2 cause frame 1 is the preloader) everything is good - I have 2 gold MovieClips on the stage(in design mode) and all 2 gold are put in the array and displayed.
On the second level I have 4 gold and only 2 of them are put in the array and displayed.
On the third level I have 7 golds designed on stage, but only 3 are displayed and put in the boulder array. 
It's almost the previous count of the gold(on the previous frame) are subtracted from the count of the next frame gold movieclips.
Someone any idea?

I am placing the Main.as code:

```
public function createLevel(){
                nextLevel = this.currentFrame + 1;
                for (var i:uint = 0; i < MovieClip(root).numChildren; i++){
                if(MovieClip(root).getChildAt(i).name=="Gold")
                {
                    this.addChild(MovieClip(root).getChildAt(i));
                    boulders.push(MovieClip(root).getChildAt(i));
                }
                }
                placePod();
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPress);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyRelease);
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateStatus);
            }
```

Here I add all children with name "Gold" in boulder array and put them on the stage.
Then add Pod and rod.

```
 private function placePod():void {
                pod = new Pod();
                addChild(pod);
                pod.createRod();
            }
```

And here is the function that listens for key press and remove boulders, then if boulder.length <= 0 removes all listeners and goToAndStop(nextLevel) and calls the createLevel() function again to load again the gold MovieClips of the next frame. Here comes the problem I described upper.

```
private function updateStatus(e:Event):void {
                if (!left && !right) {
                    pod.setSpeed(0);
                } else if (left && right) {
                    pod.setSpeed(0);
                } else if (left) {
                    pod.setSpeed(-4);
                } else {
                    pod.setSpeed(4);
                }

                for (var i in boulders) {
                    boulders[i].updateStatus();
                    if (boulders[i].remove) {
                        removeBoulder(boulders[i]);
                        boulders.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            if(boulders.length <= 0) 
            {
                pod.removeRod();
                removeChild(pod);


    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyPress);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKeyRelease);
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateStatus);
                    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(nextLevel);
                    createLevel();
                }
                }
```

Comment: By my thoughts this happens cause the MovieClip(root) children are not being removed and if in frame 2 there are 3 MovieClips with name "gold"and in frame 3 there are 5 MovieClips with name "gold", only two MovieClips are displayed cause other 3 still exists. I try this: MovieClip(root).removeChild(boulder); in the removeBoulder function but it does not work.

Comment: OK I found the solution :-) I leave a blank keyframes between every keyframe(level frame). And that works. Now my nextLevel var increase by two every time I want to go to next level instead of adding one.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to any problems regarding global properties

when you create something in flash first add an empty MovieClip give it an instance such as game or Quiz than double click into your Movie clip then make your project goback to the main timeline to type all your code and now all of your variables and what not can easly be global